# Angular - Is there any way to transform reactive form input with decimal pipe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a reactive form in which there are some numeric fields that need decimal formatting. They should be formatted as I type. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value` property of the input:

**Component TypeScript file:**

```js
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
...
public price = new FormControl('');
```

**Component HTML file:**

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Price</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    [formControl]="price"
    type="number"
    [value]="price.value | number: '1.0-0'"
  />
</mat-form-field>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-responsive-yvkfxc?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Not working mate.

Comment: How you want to format it? Did you check example that I added in the answer?

Comment: I want the input to get formatted up to specified decimal places with comma separation as I type. Yes I checked the example you posted but that didn't fit the criteria.